# Is there an efficient way to add a percent sign to every number in a set of data in R?

Tags: r

I'm currently adding labels to a plot using a dataframe of percentages that I've calculated from a set of data. The dataframe is 15 numbers long, and I would like for the final dataframe to have a percent sign after each of the numbers. The only way I can think of doing this would be to manually write out a new dataframe with the numbers from the old one, except writing them as characters and putting the percent sign after them. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's how I get the values for the dataframe:

```
new_data_set = old_data_set %>%
mutate(percentages = (round(small_number/big_number,2))*100)
```

I feel like there should be a quick way to keep that set of data while adding a percent sign to the end of each number, but I don't know how I'd do that. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `percentages = paste0((round(small_number/big_number,2))*100,"%")`

Comment: To shorten it a little more, `round((small_number / big_number) * 100)`, since the default number of digits is 0, and that's the number of digits you appear to want for the percentage. There's also a formatter in the `scales` package, but it's just a convenience wrapper around ^^